# cisco calculate ip-phone voice traffic as tag or untag?

Tags: cisco, vlan, voice

I'm almost confused about what the switch has really done with the voice traffic. 
I know access port traffic is always "**untaged**", but actually the "Switch port voice vlan (xxx)" command is used to send voice traffic as "**dot1q**" according to [Cisco Official Docs Reffrence](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_11_yj/configuration/guide/scg/swvoip.html#wp1030860)!
(And it should usually be **tagged**, because of trunk characteristic)

*So my question is should we consider one access port is both tagged and untaged traffic if we use voice vlan?! 
(but its against to expect tagged frame form acceess port i think)*

*And if not (The voice is also send as untaged), how the switch can determine its related traffic (voice, data)!?*

For Better Understanding Let's Consdier:
There is one switch, one PC, and One IP phone connected together:

SW (2960)---IPphone (7911)----PC
(The ip phone is placed between the switch "aceess port" and pc) - vlan 110: data, vlan111: voice

**SW 2960 Config:**

```
int fa 0/1
switch port mode access vlan 110
switchport access vlan 110
switchport voice vlan 111
```

The switch port for interface 0/1 is also show "access mode"
but can we should expect any tagged traffic from access port if we use voice on the same access port? and does it global for non-cisco too?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Traffic from/to the phone should be tagged. Data traffic will be untagged.

Answer (score 0):

The Cisco switch and phone use CDP to facilitate the trunk negotiation. With a non-Cisco phone, you either configure a trunk interface, or the phone may be able to use LLDP to negotiate a trunk link.

A Cisco switch and phone will negotiate a trunk link on a switch interface configured as an access interface. A VoIP phone has an internal switch, and that internal switch negotiates a trunk link with the switch to which it connects, even if it connects on an access interface. That is what the `switchport voice vlan` switch configuration enables on your switch.